# Cardinal Function-Tightness

Tags: general-topology

If $X$ is a space of product of uncountable many copies of the space $\mathbb{R}$ with the discrete topology. Then can we conclude that [tightness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tightness_(topology)) of $X$ is an uncountable cardinal.

Comment: What is $t(X)$ in this context?

Comment: @Zach: $t(X)$ is the smallest infinite cardinal $\kappa$ such that whenever $x\in\operatorname{cl}A$ for some $A\subseteq X$, then there is a $B\subseteq A$ such that $|B|\le\kappa$ and $x\in\operatorname{cl}B$.

Comment: Perhaps you could clarify what you mean by "a space of uncountably many copies...." @BrianM.Scott's answer assumes (likely correctly) that you mean the product, but this should be made explicit by an [edit] to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Let $A$ be an uncountable index set, for each $\alpha\in A$ let $D_\alpha$ be a copy of $\Bbb R$ with the discrete topology, and let $X=\prod_{\alpha\in A}D_\alpha$. For each finite $F\subseteq A$ let $x_F\in X$ be defined by

$$x_F(\alpha)=\begin{cases}
1,&\text{if }\alpha\in F\\
0,&\text{otherwise}\;,
\end{cases}$$

let $Y=\{x_F:F\subseteq A\text{ is finite}\}$, and let $y\in X$ be defined by $y(\alpha)=1$ for all $\alpha\in A$. Clearly $y\in\operatorname{cl}Y$. Suppose now that $Z$ is a countable subset of $Y$. Let $C=\bigcup\{F\subseteq A:x_F\in Z\}$; then $C$ is a countable subset of $A$, so there is an $\alpha\in A\setminus C$. Let $U=\{x\in X:x(\alpha)=1\}$; then $U$ is open in $X$, $y\in U$, and $U\cap Z=\varnothing$, so $y\notin\operatorname{cl}Z$. It follows that $t(X)\ge\omega_1$.

Essentially the same argument works for any product of uncountably many spaces, so long as each of the spaces contains two points, one of which can be separated from the other by an open set.

Comment: Thank you Prof. Brian M. Scott

Comment: @ana: You're welcome.